# Error when plotting values over dates with GGPLOT2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a r dataframe with 3 columns,

- `Locatie` (type string)
- `Periode` (R date or posixct object, both give the same error)
- `Meldingen` (numeric)

I try to plot `Meldingen` over the time stored in `Periode`
having a different line for each `Locatie`

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
# Mutate the date string column into a datetime object column
monthlyData <- data[grepl("MM", data$Periode),]
monthlyData <- aggregate(Meldingen ~ Periode+Locatie, monthlyData, sum)
monthlyData$Periode <- as.POSIXct(paste0(monthlyData$Periode, "01"), format="20%yMM%m%d")
yearlyData <- data[grepl("JJ", data$Periode),]
yearlyData <- aggregate(Meldingen ~ Periode+Locatie, yearlyData, sum)
yearlyData$Periode <- as.POSIXct(paste0(yearlyData$Periode, "01"), format="20%yJJ%m%d")

ggplot(monthlyData, aes(x = as.POSIXct(Periode),y = Meldingen, color = Locatie)) + geom_line()
```

A small overview of what my data looks like:
[image]

When running this script I get the following error:

```
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) (DataVizualisation.R#21): 'to' must be a finite number
```

line 21 mentioned in the error i where i call ggplot

Wy do I encounter this issue?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Also, please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Calling `as.POSIXct(.)` on numeric data should have filed with `Error: 'origin' must be supplied`. There may be a better way to do all of what you're doing here, sample data would make seeing that (and testing code) a bit easier. Thanks!